# Routing between tables in nftables

Tags: nftables

I'm looking for an equivalent to this rule.

```
ip -4 rule add fwmark 0xfeed table 64
```

I understand fwmark selector can be accomplished using conntrack support. Is there anyway to specify that  packets use a different routing table?